# ng-hide /ng-show do not work after the model is updated

Tags: angularjs

I have the following

```
var model = 
{
 UserInfo :null ,
 PlatformID : 1
}
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller("UCtrl",['$scope','$http','$window', function ($scope, $http,$window) { 
$scope.Info =model ;
$scope.SearchUser = function() {
           $http({
            method:"POST",
            url : '/FindUser',
            data: {UserID : 9999}

        }).success(function(data){

            $scope.Info.UserInfo = data;

        });

    };
});

<div ng-hide="{{Info.UserInfo === null}}" >

</div>
```

When a user is searched for , the Info.User is updated via $http post via

```
$scope.Info.User = data ;
```

The ng-hide part does not show after the data is assigned to the Info.User object even though  there is data.

Comment: So the problem is probably somewhere else in your app. Somewhere that's not in your question. ;-)

Comment: Are you sure that `data` is not null?

Comment: Yes , data is not null

Comment: Did you try to remove brackets? I mean code `<div ng-hide="Info.UserInfo === null">`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't user {{}} inside ng-if. Expression will be executed anyway:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="Example">
    <div data-ng-controller="Cntrl">
        <div ng-hide="UserInfo === null" >
            User info
        </div>
        <button data-ng-click="toggle()">Toggle</button>
    </div>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module("Example", [])
        .controller("Cntrl", function ($scope) {
            $scope.UserInfo = null;
            $scope.toggle = function () {
                if ($scope.UserInfo === null) {
                    $scope.UserInfo = 'some value';
                } else {
                    $scope.UserInfo = null;
                }
            };
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: here is another fiddle with code more like yours: http://jsfiddle.net/kpLe544u/3/

I think the issue is that you haven't declared a controller in your HTML so you cannot access the variable Info.UserInfo from that div.

Excerpts from my fiddle: (http://jsfiddle.net/kpLe544u/2/)

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <div ng-show="Info.User">data here</div>
      <div ng-show="Info.Test">this won't show</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**controller.js**

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.Info = {}; 
  $scope.Info.User = "blah blah";
  $scope.Info.Test = null;
}
```

Comment: I have a controller and directives set